# Using a try/catch with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I thought I had resolved this but I obviously haven't and was hoping someone might be able to shed some light on what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get a piece of PHP code to check a file on a server and based on the response, perform an action. The file is a simple text file which has either the word "true" or "false" written on it. If the file exists or the return is "true" the script goes to one url. If it doesn't exist (i.e. server is unavailable) or the return is "false", the script goes to a second url. The following is the snippet of code I have used up until now.

```
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = 'https://[domain]/test.htm';

$options[CURLOPT_PORT] = 443;
$options[CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = false;
$options[CURLOPT_FAILONERROR] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 10;

// Preset $response var to false and output
$fb = "";
$response = "false";
echo '<p class="response1">'.$response.'</p>';

try {
    $curl = curl_init();
    echo curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    // If curl request returns a value, I set it to the var here. 
    // If the file isn't found (server offline), the try/catch fails and var should stay as false.
    $fb = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    throw new Exception("Invalid URL",0,$e);
}

if($fb == "true" || $fb == "false") {
    echo '<p class="response2">'.$fb.'</p>';
    $response = $fb;
}

// If cURL was successful, $response should now be true, otherwise it will have stayed false.
echo '<p class="response3">'.$response.'</p>';
```

This example here, only goes through the handling of the file test. The content of "test.htm" is either "true" or "false".

This may seem like a convoluted way of doing it, but the file is on a third party server (I have no control over this) and needs to be checked as the third party vendor may decide to force a failover to the second url, while doing maintenance work on the first url. Hence why I can't just check for the file's existance.

I have tested on a local setup and it all behaves as expected. The problem arises when the file is not there. The $fb = curl_exec($curl); doesn't fail, it just returns an empty value. I had thought that, as this is on an IIS PHP server, the issue might be PHP related on the server, but I am now seeing this issue locally (on a Unix system).

If anyone could shed any light on what I might be doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it. There may also be a much shorter way of testing this file, I could be going the long way around to do this, so really appreciate any help.

T

Comment: Couldn't you just throw an exception when `$fb` is empty in addition to the exception thrown by your try-catch block?

Comment: Don't really need to throw an exception on the $fb being empty. The response variable is set to false, and all $fb is being used for is to check if the state is different and then resets response. But the more I look at it the more wrong it looks. I've been at this for 8 hours straight, so I can't see it anymore!!!

Comment: Oh, I see. I paid too much attention to the fact that you talked about curl_exec() failing and that you threw a new exception in your catch statement and didn't read the comments closely enough.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

cURL does not throw exceptions, it is a thin wrapper for the C library it binds to.

I've modified your example to use a more correct pattern.

```
$options[CURLOPT_URL] = 'https://[domain]/test.htm';

$options[CURLOPT_PORT] = 443;
$options[CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = false;
$options[CURLOPT_FAILONERROR] = true;
$options[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true; // curl_exec will not return true if you use this, it will instead return the request body
$options[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 10;

// Preset $response var to false and output
$fb = "";
$response = false;// don't quote booleans
echo '<p class="response1">'.$response.'</p>';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
// If curl request returns a value, I set it to the var here. 
// If the file isn't found (server offline), the try/catch fails and var should stay as false.
$fb = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($fb !== false) {
    echo '<p class="response2">'.$fb.'</p>';
    $response = $fb;
}

// If cURL was successful, $response should now be true, otherwise it will have stayed false.
echo '<p class="response3">'.$response.'</p>';
```

Comment: Awesome, cheers dude, I'll give that a go. One Q, you say don't quote booleans, but the response off the file on the server will be a string. Will it automatically be treated as a boolean?

Comment: Made a slight modification to this to test the status code of the header too, rather than testing for the file existing...

Comment: I didn't realise you were comparing it to a string, but $fb is either going to be boolean false or whatever string is returned in the request. With PHP's typing that's why I used the strong comparison operator !==

Answer (score -3):

We can get error from following code

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
    echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18015365/2442749

Comment: Please vote existing answer as duplicate instead of referencing other question in the answer