# No response from cURL function

Tags: php, curl

I have written the following function, which was code I used somewhere else and modified slightly to work as a function (using $url in function parameters):

```
function curl2str($url) {
    $cURL = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $data = curl_exec($cURL);
    curl_close($cURL);
    return $data;
}
```

I simply want a function to return a URL into a string, for a quick and easy API.  The URL I am passing it is valid and works fine when I put it into a browser.  I am calling it like so:

`<?=curl2str("**valid URL here**");?>`

For some reason it is just returning false.  What am I doing wrong?

**update**
When I put this questions URL into as `$url`, I get a response.  But when I use my custom URL, which works fine in the browser, and simply display's a list of files in the directory, I get bool:false.

**update 2**
It would seem that any domain works fine, apart from the one that I am trying to access.  It just so happens that this is a root domain on the same server, I am running this script from a subdomain, but because of basedir_restrictions I cannot access a folder from the subdomain.  So I wrote a little php to get the contents of the folder, and output it to the browser as a serialized array (JSON is not installed).  But I cannot get a response from this root domain at all.  It works fine in the browser, just not in cURL.  And everything else works fine in cURL.

:(

Comment: have you tried calling curl from the command line with exactly the options you set inside your function?

Comment: use curl_error($cURL) to get error message.

Comment: yes, when i var_dump($data) it says 'bool:false'

Comment: Okay, update: I just put the URL for this question in there.  So for some reason the page I am trying tog get it displaying false in cURL, and data when I go to it via a browser :(

Comment: consider using [Fiddler 2](http://fiddler2.com/) to tap into the actual data transmitted, if necessary (you might have to setup curl calls to use the client-side ad hoc proxy fiddler will install).

Comment: just echo your url, it might be getting encoded or something....and type 1 instead of  true in your third line

Comment: Your codes wrong. Put `;` after `curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)`. Its working for me

Comment: @Bora sorry yes I have already spotted that, But didnt update the ticket :P

Comment: Hmm, i thought you run codes without `;`. OK

Comment: `echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';`
`echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';`
`echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';` use these for debug it

Comment: I think it is the bloody open_basedir restriction stopping me from looking at my own domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this function:

```
function curl($url, $cookie = false, $post = false, $header = false, $follow_location = false, $referer=false,$proxy=false)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $follow_location);
    if ($cookie) {
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    }
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    $response = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this code into your function:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
    echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

**Note: `curl_errno($ch);`** return error number>0 if any error occurs from cURL and use **`curl_error($ch);`** to see what is the error from cURL.

Comment: You probably meant the `curl_errno` to be **after** `curl_exec` :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Good eye, its after curl_exec, i just updated my answer Thanks :)

Comment: There is mistake in concatenation in your answer, echo 'Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);